How to implement 3rd party data fetches in Vite + Vue web-application?
I want to use 3rd party function (actually, it is mine, but written in different time and different file), which requests data via fetch function.
In my Vue + Vite application I import that function and call it. However by default in Vite environment I get CORS error (localhost -> fandom.com connection)
In case of CORS errors Vite suggests to create small proxy via its config file. However this proxy listens only to localhost requests, whilst my "3rd-party function" already calls to specific outbound address, and I cannot change it inside Vue code.
In .vue I have this line:
import fetchWikiData from "@sancho-pansa/parse-wiki-data";
let cardsTable = await fetchWikiData(5); // Calls for data about cards from 5th expansion of the game

That fetchWikiData() function makes call to https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/api.php and by default that site name is immutable from Vue application.
So, my question is: what should I do inside Vite settings or in app in general to overcome this type of CORS error?
I tried to look for solution in Vite config documentation, but it only provides examples for localhost proxy, for example, I make http://localhost/proxy request and it redirects me to fandom.com/api.php. However in my case I have complete function, which sends and processes request, so I cannot basically interfere with it and change address in it to some localhost/proxy.

The question is why third-party lib makes requests to api restricted with cors and whether api allows to whitelist a domain including localhost. If it's not, you have a problem

Actually, this "third-party lib" is mine.
I wrote it as a test and previously launched it from console in NodeJS environment. where it worked just fine, and then I decided to implement it into app with GUI.

If API is expected to be used on server side, i.e. doesn't provide proper CORS policy, you're limited to proxying the requests through Node or else and cannot use it directly in a browser. I can't say if it's so for fandom.com but it looks like that. Vite's proxy is intended only for development, you can make it work by doing the requests to localhost instead of fandom.com, but this needs to be solved in production somehow any way

Thank you for your answer.
I've already seen advice to use proxy, so I will move in that way.
I just thought, that I'm missing some vital detail in my development.
Would it right to say, that if I want to write some small function with fetch feature, I must leave a window for redirecting that fetch to some proxy, am I right?

I'd suggest to add a parameter to provide custom baseurl for such fetch functions, so it would be possible to make requests to /myapi/api.php instead of leagueoflegends.fandom.com/api.php . Where /myapi/ can be powered by vite devproxy or nginx or else

As per Estus Flask answers, this issue has several roots.
Firstly, CORS errors pop up in browser environment, which means that correct fetch request handling in NodeJS environment does not guarantee, that the same fetch will work correctly in any browser due to established CORS policy in most browsers.
Secondly, if one writes a reusable function (or lib) for data-fetching with intention to use it in browser environment, one should provide some kind of mechanism to allow end-user of that reusable function/lib to proxy its requests due to guaranteed CORS issue, e.g. some kind of base URL to provide, or proxy address at function start, etc.
NB: "fetch" here relates to Fetch API of JavaScript.
